# Chef template/file updated_by_last_action broken?

Tags: templates, chef-infra

I'm using chef's built in template resource and it looks like template's updated_by_last_action? is not implemented. Now this seems pretty impossible, given that template is a fairly basic resource. So what am I missing?

Evidence of why I think template updated_by_last_action? is broken

(1)

```
t = template "some file" do
  source "someerbfile.erb"
  action :create
end
Chef::Log.info("-------updated_by_last_action? : #{t.updated_by_last_action?}"
```

on running always gives false - whether the file has been updated or not.

(2)
Looking at the implementation of template and it's super class file here https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/file.rb and https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider/template.rb , I don't see any code which is setting the value of updated_by_last_action or updated to true.

Comment: Here is your code that updates the status: https://github.com/opscode/chef/blob/master/lib/chef/provider.rb (`set_updated_status`). Now what about reading the manual and answering this question yourself? http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chef run consists of two distinct phases (not counting preparation - detailed view is on the Opscode's wiki [Anatomy of a Chef Run](http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Anatomy+of+a+Chef+Run) page): *resource compilation* and *convergence*.

During resource compilation, the recipe files are evaluated, but the resulting resources are only collected. The `template "some_file" …` call only *creates* a Chef::Resource::Template object that is added to the collection.

After *all* the recipe files are evaluated, in the convergence phase, chef-client goes over the resource collection and calls the providers for each.

You are checking the `updated_by_last_action?` attribute still in the recipe, which means you are calling it during resource compilation phase. No provider has been called yet, so the resource haven't been updated.

Depending on the result you want to achieve, most likely you want to use [notifications](http://docs.opscode.com/resource_common_notifications.html). If the problem at hand is more complex, you may need to write your own [lightweight resource & provider](http://docs.opscode.com/lwrp.html).